# Vehicles are missing in default CryEngine 5 installation

Tags: cryengine

I installed CryEngine 5 from an official site. Now I want to add a vehicle to a level.

As described in [Beginners manual](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/CEMANUAL/Adding+Vehicles), I need to

> open the **Create Object** tool, go to **Entity** and expand **Vehicles** in the list that appears in the bottom of the tool.

However, there is no **Vehicles** item:
[image]

How to add `DefaultVehicle` into my level?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question... Are you using the GameSDK project or another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in CryEngine 5 you need to download GameSDK, because engine does not have this editor by default.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using one of the many templates from the Cryengine launcher. In those templates you have almost nothing, so you would have to implement them by yourself.

Here you can find some useful resource to register a new vehicle entity

- [Vehicle System overview](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC4/Vehicle+System)
- [Vehicle Setup Tutorial](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC4/Vehicle+Setup+Tutorial)
- [XML Setup Guide](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC4/XML+Setup+Guide)

And [here](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC2/Vehicle+Creation) you can find a small guide on vehicle modelling and setup.

**But** if you want just start using a vehicle **without having to implement it** from scratch, I suggest you to download and use the [CRYENGINE GameSDK Sample Project](https://www.cryengine.com/marketplace/product/cryengine-sample-project-gamesdk) that comes with some cool stuff, such as **different categories of vehicles**, particles, **objects** and an **actual player**.

Please note that these guides from the **official documentation** were developed for CryEngine 3.X but they *should* work also for CryEngine 5.X

I hope I helped you :)